# unit testing if/else statement based on promise result

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am testing a controller with the function listed below. My problem is that the if else statment is based on the result of a promise. How can I capture the result of this promise in order to test the if else statements? At the moment I keep getting `Can't find variable data`

```
 $scope.get = function (accountId, campaignId, requestId) {

        campaignBuyRequestService.getCampaignBuyRequest(global.activeOrganizationId, accountId, campaignId, requestId).then(function (data) {

            if (data) {
                $.each(data.requestActions, function (index) {
                    if (data.requestActions[index].statusCode === 10001000) {
                        data.requestActions[index].statusCodeDisplayText = "Sent";
                        data.requestActions[index].iconClass = "fa fa-arrow-left";
                    } else if (data.requestActions[index].statusCode === 10002000) {
                        data.requestActions[index].statusCodeDisplayText = "Opted In";
                        data.requestActions[index].iconClass = "fa fa-arrow-right";
                    } else if (data.requestActions[index].statusCode === 10003000) {
                        data.requestActions[index].statusCodeDisplayText = "Rejected";
                        data.requestActions[index].iconClass = "fa fa-exclamation-circle";
                    } else if (data.requestActions[index].statusCode === 10004000) {
                        data.requestActions[index].statusCodeDisplayText = "Withdrawn";
                        data.requestActions[index].iconClass = "fa fa-exclamation-circle";
                    } else if (data.requestActions[index].statusCode === 10005000) {
                        data.requestActions[index].statusCodeDisplayText = "Activated";
                        data.requestActions[index].iconClass = "fa fa-play";
                    } else if (data.requestActions[index].statusCode === 10006000) {
                        data.requestActions[index].statusCodeDisplayText = "Canceled";
                        data.requestActions[index].iconClass = "fa fa-exclamation-circle";
                    } else if (data.requestActions[index].statusCode === 10007000) {
                        data.requestActions[index].statusCodeDisplayText = "Paused";
                        data.requestActions[index].iconClass = "fa fa-pause";
                    } else {
                        data.requestActions[index].statusCodeDisplayText = "Unknown";
                        data.requestActions[index].iconClass = "fa fa-question";
                    }
                });
            }

            $scope.buyRequest = data;
        });
```

My test looks like this:

```
it('should assign statusCodeDisplayText and Icon class based on status code', function () {
        spyOn(scope, "get");
        scope.get(buyRequest.requestId, mockStateParams.accountId, mockStateParams.campaignId);
        scope.data = spyOn(mockBuyRequestService, 'getCampaignBuyRequest').and.callThrough;
        scope.$digest();

        expect(scope.data.requestActions[0].statusCodeDisplayText).toEqual('Sent');
        expect(scope.data.requestActions[0].iconClass).toEqual('fa fa-arrow-left');
        expect(scope.data.requestActions[1].statusCodeDisplayText).toEqual('Withdrawn');
        expect(scope.data.requestActions[1].iconClass).toEqual('fa fa-exclamation-circle');
    });
```

bonus question: why does this test not pass? Shouldn't scope.buyRequest be automaticly updated when get is called?

```
it('should make a request for campaigns and assign them to buyRequests', function () {
        scope.get(mockStateParams.accountId, mockStateParams.campaignId, buyRequest.requestId);
        scope.$digest();

        expect(scope.buyRequest).toEqual(buyRequest);
    });
```

Comment: In your first question, it looks like your expects should be looking at `scope.data.//...` rather than just `data.//...`. Similarly, for your bonus question, in your `campaignBuyRequestService` you are assigning data to `$scope.buyRequest` (singular), but your test case is testing against `$scope.buyRequests` (plural)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! It still does not quite work but my oversight certainly did not help. I updated the code

Comment: First, I think a `switch` statement would be a lot cleaner than all that `if...else if` stuff. Second, we'll need to see what `mockBuyRequestService.getCampaignBuyRequest` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about what you currently have in your test suite, here's how I'd set it up...

```
var campaignBuyRequestService, deferred, scope;

beforeEach(function() {
    campaignBuyRequestService = jasmine.createSpyObj('campaignBuyRequestService', ['getCampaignBuyRequest']);

    module('module-that-you-are-testing', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('campaignBuyRequestService', campaignBuyRequestService);
    });

    inject(function($q) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        campaignBuyRequestService.getCampaignBuyRequest.and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
    });

    // assign scope however you're doing it already
});
```

Now you can test the conditions based on what's resolved by the promise. For example...

```
it('sent status', inject(function($rootScope) {
    var sentAction = { statusCode: 10001000 },
        data = {
            requestActions: [sentAction]
        };
    deferred.resolve(data);

    scope.get(...);

    expect(campaignBuyRequestService.getCampaignBuyRequest).toHaveBeenCalled();

    $rootScope.$apply(); // call this to run a digest cycle and resolve promises

    expect(sentAction.statusCodeDisplayText).toBe('Sent');
    expect(sentAction.iconClass).toBe('fa fa-arrow-left');
    expect(scope.buyRequest).toBe(data);
}));
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Thanks Phil this helps